# First character of \ref{<label>}

Tags: xstring, catcodes, hungarian

Practically, I would like to decide if a reference to a label begins 1 or not.
The question has some relevance in Hungarian.
The idea was to use `xstring` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{polyglossia}\setdefaultlanguage{hungarian}
\usepackage[hungarian]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
   \label{eq:ab}
   a=b
\end{equation}
The reference to the label \texttt{eq:ab},
which is actually \ref{eq:ab},
\IfBeginWith{\ref{eq:ab}}{1}{starts}{does not start} 1.
\end{document}
```

It seems that the output of `\ref{eq:ab}` begins with some fancy character, definitely not 1.

I am looking for a solution using `lualatex` or `xelatex`. Even if I remove `polyglossia`, using `pdflatex` also produces a pdf file which is not the same as I expected. Do not use `babel`, please.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: This MWE does not use `hyperref`. Is that also the case for your real document? Hyperref changes the definition and output of `\ref`, which would make a significant difference for answering this question, therefore it would be good to know if you indeed want a solution _without_ hyperref.

Comment: @marijn Thank you for the comment. Yes, yes finally I need `hyperref`. Even more I will use `polyglossia`. I change the mwe with a more realistic setup.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`\ref` is unsuitable to retrieve the data, the command is robust and with hyperref is also contains code to create a link. Use the refcount package and its `\getrefnumber` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{refcount} %loaded by hyperref

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
   \label{eq:ab}
   a=b
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   \label{eq:bb}
   a=b
\end{equation}
The reference to the label \texttt{eq:ab},
which is actually \ref{eq:ab},

\IfBeginWith{\getrefnumber{eq:ab}}{1}{starts}{does not start} 1.

\IfBeginWith{\getrefnumber{eq:bb}}{1}{starts}{does not start} 1.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: An `expl3` version would be welcome

Comment: @egreg an expl3 version from what? \getrefnumber?

Comment: No, in order to avoid `xstring`

Comment: @egreg I thought about that, but then decided the answer would be clearer if I change only the really relevant part.

Answer (score 1):

A “packageless” implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\refstartswithoneTF}{mmm}
 {% #1 = label, #2 = true text, #3 = false text
  \mgy_ref_starts:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \mgy_ref_number:n
 {
  \cs_if_exist:cTF { r@#1 }
   { \exp_last_unbraced:Nf \use_i:nn { \use:c { r@#1 } } }
   { 0 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \mgy_ref_starts:nnn
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \str_head:e { \mgy_ref_number:n { #1 } } } { 1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_head:n { e }

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
   \label{eq:a}
   a=b
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
   \label{eq:b}
   a=b
\end{equation}

\setcounter{equation}{9}

\begin{equation}
   \label{eq:c}
   a=b
\end{equation}

The reference to the label \texttt{eq:a},
which is actually \ref{eq:a},
\refstartswithoneTF{eq:a}{starts}{does not start} with 1.

The reference to the label \texttt{eq:b},
which is actually \ref{eq:b},
\refstartswithoneTF{eq:b}{starts}{does not start} with 1.

The reference to the label \texttt{eq:c},
which is actually \ref{eq:c},
\refstartswithoneTF{eq:c}{starts}{does not start} with 1.

\end{document}
```

[image]

What does the incantation

```
\exp_last_unbraced:Nf \use_i:nn { \use:c { r@#1 } }
```

do?

The first instruction tell TeX to jump over the next token, that is, `\use_i:nn`, and to recursively expand the contents of the braced group, leaving the unbraced result in the input stream.

Say that `#1` is `eq:c` for the sake of the example. Then `\use:c{r@eq:c}` first produces `\r@eq:c` (a token that cannot be ordinarily written) which is expanded. Such expansion is always of the form

```
{<ref>}{<pageref>}
```

in the present case `{10}{1}`. Now TeX will see

```
\use_i:nn {10}{1}
```

and this just leaves `10` in the input stream. This is used in `\mgy_ref_starts:nnn`. Note that `\str_head:e` fully expands its argument, so `10` becomes `1`, and we eventually get

```
\str_if_eq:nnTF { 1 } { 1 } {starts} {does not start}
```

which returns the true branch.

With `eq:b` we eventually get

```
\str_if_eq:nnTF { 2 } { 1 } {starts} {does not start}
```

which returns the false branch.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Could you, please, write a short sentence on the usage of `use_i:nn` above. (Where is the second argument?, etc.)

Comment: @MGy The expansion of `\r@<label>` has always the form `{<ref>}{<pageref>}`, so `\use_i:nn` chooses the first group. I added some other explanations.